# Wordpress, how to start with an empty theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been working on Wordpress for a month creating themes. Otherwise, when I'm starting a new project, I'm always starting with an existing theme that I am modifying.

What I want, is to clean perfectly a theme and add to it what I need for the website.

But, my Wordpress knowledge aren't enough to do it. So, I'm asking you if you know a great book, website etc, where they are explaining simply how to create a new theme (understand every features of Wordpress, explaining every functions in the functions.php file, how to add  correctly Wordpress post content).

Thanks

Comment: Just use Google.  There's plenty of info out there on theming.  If you just want a pre-built starter theme to customize then I'd recommend Bones.  You can find it here: http://themble.com/bones/

Comment: "Just use Google", google took me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Romain asked:

> ...how to create a new theme (understand every features of Wordpress,
>   explaining every functions in the functions.php file, how to add
>   correctly Wordpress post content).

Start with the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page which is

> the online manual for WordPress and a living repository for WordPress
>   information and documentation.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was create all the files and save them in a folder, then upload them as needed. I copied them from this simple tutorial and although says its to create a designed theme, it has nothing but basic blank theme:

http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-build-a-custom-wordpress-theme-from-scratch

Answer (score 2):

You can download **simplest possible theme for wordpress** here:

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/simplest

After you take a look at this and create some theme using this simple theme - you will better understand Wordpress Codex, and you can follow @markratledge suggestions about Codex.

Anyway, I decided to not read whole codex and im using this theme ("Simplest") as boilerplate for my themes.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Starkers by Elliot Jay Stocks:

- Intro: http://viewportindustries.com/products/starkers/
- Demo: http://starkers.viewportindustries.com/
- Github: https://github.com/viewportindustries/starkers

It helped me out a bunch of times to start from scratch. It has the basic files and no CSS.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look tonight

Answer (score -1):

the wordpress.org will be your best starting point, for your

> (understand every features of Wordpress, explaining every functions in the functions.php file, how to add correctly Wordpress post content).

Answer (score -3):

You can make WordPress themes from the scratch by following some methods

> 1. By using **Youtube**, but that'll be not very professional
> 2. By using **Google**, yes you will find many sites that will show you the process and this is efficient and free
> 3. By using **Udemy** or **Lynda**, you will learn about the whole process with the necessary knowledge like the hierarchy of wordpress, tools & standards for wordpress etc.
> 4. By using **wordpress.org**, this is most desirable and professional way of learning wordpress as this is the main place for all the things happening around the WordPress.

Comment: Why would you put the most desirable thing last?

Comment: the most important thing should at the last for it's importance